# Coordinating two UIView animations on UIButton down/up

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I'm trying to build an animation around a UIButton. The UIButton has a UIImageView that contains an image that I'd like to shrink when the UIButton is held down and then when the UIButton is let go, I'd like to play a separate animation that does a bounce.

The issue I'm experiencing right now is that the 2nd part of the animation doesn't seem to play if I press down and then up very quickly. If I press and hold (wait for the first animation to finish), then let go, it seems to work fine.

Here's the relevant code:

```
-(void)pressedDown
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                self.heartPart.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1);
            } completion:nil];
}

-(void)pressedUp
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                                      delay:0.0
                     usingSpringWithDamping:20
                      initialSpringVelocity:200
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                 animations:^{
                                     self.heartPart.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                                 }
                                 completion:nil];
            }];
}
```

In my `ViewDidLoad` I add the following:

```
[self.heartButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(pressedUp)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.heartButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(PressedDown)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Any idea how I can get the two animations to sequence and not interrupt each other even on a quick press?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the first animation to complete before the second one starts, even if you do a quick touch?

Comment: Yep, right now it seems like the 2nd animation doesn't fire at all because the transform hasn't completed on the first.

Comment: Do you really need the second animation to not start until the user lifts their finger? It doesn't seem like people would hold the touch for any length of time anyway, in which case you could only have one method, and add the second animation to the completion block of the first..

Comment: Lifting the finger in the button commits something on the server so I want to play a louder animation. If you lift the finger off not on the button then I want it to cancel (standard button behavior). It's not necessary, but it's a nice touch I'm hoping to do. :)

Comment: There are many ways how you can chain animations. The most obvious would be to have a serial `NSOperationQueue`. This way you can even cancel animations that didn't run yet and schedule new ones when user moves their finger fast back and forth. Just keep in mind that animations have to be dispatched on main thread, while `NSOperations` would merely spin off and wait for animations to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential plan of action. Keep two global variables, `BOOL buttonPressed` and `NSDate *buttonPressDate`. When the button is pressed, you should set `buttonPressed` to true and set `buttonPressDate` to the current date. Now in the touch up method, you would set `buttonPressed` to false and check whether the time interval between `buttonPressDate` and the current date is greater than the duration of the animation. If it is, then run the touch up animation; if not, return. In the completion block of the touch down method, you would check if the button was still pressed. If it is, then do nothing; if it's not pressed anymore, then run the touch up animation.

The effect you'll get using this approach should be the following: if you tap the button quickly, it will run the full 0.2-second shrink animation and then run the enlarge animation in sequence.

Now, if you don't want the touch down animation to run in the case of a quick touch, you should probably delay the first animation and check if the button is still pressed when you start it. If it was a quick touch, you would run a modified animation that covered both the touch down and touch up phases.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the following :-

```
 //Set only one target with TouchUpInside.
  [self.heartButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(pressedUp)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)pressedDown
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            self.heartPart.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1);
        } 
    completion:

    [self pressedUp];
    //Or
    [self performSelector:@selector(pressedUp) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5]; 

  ];       
}

 -(void)pressedUp
 {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                                  delay:0.0
                 usingSpringWithDamping:20
                  initialSpringVelocity:200
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                             animations:^{
                                 self.heartPart.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                             }
                             completion:nil];
        }];
 }
```

This way as first animation is completed then next animation will start But my concern is that it won't look appropriate and it would be a bit long animation to show to a user. Rest it's upto your app design and what all it is going to achieve with it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are familiar with the concept of operations. If not then `NSOperations` allow you to keep your code modular and enable you to set the order of execution.

You could create a custom subclass of `NSOperation` and run animation within its execution block, then add operations with animations on queue each time user interacts with the button.

Apart from [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/), there is a great example of how to subclass `NSOperation` available on Github:

https://github.com/robertmryan/AFHTTPSessionOperation/blob/master/Source/AsynchronousOperation.m

Based on that "blueprint" for your custom operations, it's very trivial to achieve what you want, i.e.:

```
@interface PressDownAnimationOperation : AsynchronousOperation

- (instancetype)initWithView:(UIView *)view;

@end

@implementation PressDownAnimationOperation {
    UIView *_view;
}

- (instancetype)initWithView:(UIView *)view {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _view = view;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main {
    // dispatch UIKit related stuff on main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // animate
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                _view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished){
              // mark operation as finished
              [self completeOperation];
            }];
    });
}

@end
```

Now in order to run animations you need to create `NSOperationQueue`. You can keep it within your view controller, i.e.:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSOperationQueue *_animationQueue;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _animationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // limit queue to run single operation at a time
    _animationQueue.maxOperationCount = 1;
}

@end
```

Now when you want to chain animations, you simply create new operation, add it to queue and that's it, i.e.:

```
- (void)pressedDown {
    NSOperation *animationOperation = [[PressDownAnimationOperation alloc] init];

   [_animationQueue addOperation:animationOperation];
}
```

If user taps too fast and you notice that your operation queue is clogged with animations, you can simply cancel all animations before adding new one, i.e.:

```
[_animationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```